# How can I convert this IF statement to use in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have the following IF statement `=IF(LEN(F2)>LEN(H2),F2,H2)`

This just checks which is longer between F2 and H2 and populates I2 with the longest. When I put this in VBA it comes out as  `=IF(LEN(G1048558)>LEN(I1048558),G1048558,I1048558)`in my spreadsheet

How could I fix this?

```
Sub PopulateI()

Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(LEN(R[-20]C[-2])>LEN(R[-20]C),R[-20]C[-2],R[-20]C)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi I have now included this.

Comment: `"=IF(LEN(RC[-3])>LEN(RC[-1]),RC[-3],RC[-1])"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the `AutoFill` and write the formula to the entire range in one step.

If it's easier, you can use the A1-style formula instead of the current R1C1-style formula.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("I2:I" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(LEN(F2)>LEN(H2),F2,H2)"
```

Or as noted by @Scott Craner, you can fix the R1C1-style formula (which is the real issue):

```
Range("I2:I" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-3])>LEN(RC[-1]),RC[-3],RC[-1])"
```